# Regex expresion issue removing ':/'

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

From a string I need to remove everything that is not a letter, number, space, or '-'.

I use:

```
regex = re.compile('^[,?!`@#$%^&*()+=.:/]+')
name = regex.sub('', my_text)
```

But if I have the text:

```
lorem ipsum: 100 gb/s and beyond
```

My regex expression from the example above, doesn't remove `':'`, `'/'`

Comment: And what is the problem with the given input string?

Comment: : and / are not removed with the regex that I use

Comment: Please add all such explanation to the question itself

Comment: What should be the expected output for the string you mentioned `lorem ipsum: 100 gb/s and beyond`?

Comment: lorem ipsum 100 gbs and beyond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to capture all possible symbols, dingbats, and whatever other characters you want to remove, I would recommend implementing "everything that is not, letter, number, space, or '-'" literally:

```
regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]')
name = regex.sub('', my_text)
```

You can use character classes in your character class. If you are OK with underscores being a letter, and you want to support Unicode letters, the following is more concise:

```
 regex = re.compile('[^\w -]')
```

The problem with your original expression is that `^` outside a character class matches the start of a line. Your expression can only remove the characters you specified from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the ^ (start of line)
On a side note the the + is not mandatory

```
regex = re.compile('[,?!`@#$%^&*()+=.:/]')
name = regex.sub('', my_text)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/DjTvwL/1

I re-read your description and since you do not want 'everything but letter, digits and space' your current regex does not fit : it let [ _ " and so on... so you better use a negative regex :

```
import re
my_regex = re.compile('([^0-9A-Za-z\-\s])') # 0- 9 => digits; A-z => letter; \- the '-' char; \s any whitespace
my_text = 'lorem ipsum: 100 gb/s and beyond'

name = my_regex.sub('', my_text)

print(name)
```